# Erro ao exibir valor guardado na $_SESSION no cabeçalho

Tags: php, html

Gostaria de saber em qual parte meu código está dando erro, já varri ele e nada, se eu colocar no `echo $_SESSION['senha']` ele exibe a senha, mas se eu colocar o nome ele exibe o valor 1.. Eu quero colocar tipo.. Bem vindo, `echo $_SESSION['nome'];`

página "envia_login.php" onde é recebido os valores do campo de formulario de login..

```
<?php

session_start();
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
include("conexao.php");

if(empty($_POST['nome']) || empty($_POST['senha'])){
    header('location:chat_login.php');
    exit();
}

$nome = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['nome']);
$senha = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['senha']);

$query = "select * from usuarios where nome = '$nome' and senha = '$senha'";

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$row = mysqli_num_rows($result);


if($row == 1){
    $_SESSION['nome'] = $nome && $_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;

    //ESSE TRECHO ABAIXO FIZ VERIFICAÇÃO DE NÍVEL DE USUÁRIOS PARA REDIRECIONAR A PÁGINAS DIFERENTES------------! vou usar futuramente.
    while ($verifica_nivel = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $nivel = $verifica_nivel['nivel'];
            if ($nivel == 1) {
                header('location: chat_home.php');
            }else{
                header('location: chat_home.php');
            }

    }
}

else{
    echo "<script>alert('USUÁRIO NÃO CADASTRADO OU DADOS INVÁLIDOS!');</script>";
    echo "<script>window.location='chat_login.php';</script>";
    exit();
}
?>
```

Página "chat_home.php"

Inicio a sessão com verifica login que verifica campos vazios e redireciona imediatamente.

```
<?php
session_start();
include("verifica_login.php");
?>
```

Trecho do código que estou inserindo o echo `$_SESSION`

```
<i id="title-header"><i class="medium material-icons">forum</i> 
    <strong>SUPORTE TI</strong>
</i>
     <p>Bem Vindo, <b><?php echo $_SESSION['nome']; ?></b></p>
```

Está exibindo da seguinte maneira.... Bem Vindo, 1

Answer (score 0):

Da forma que você fez a atribuição não vai funcionar porque você está fazendo uma condição. Remova o `&&` e faça atribuição como no exemplo abaixo.

```
$_SESSION['nome'] = $nome;
$_SESSION['senha'] = $senha;
```